# Extra variable or existing variable

Tags: java

I want to ask about is there any impact(s) (such as performance) in between these two types of codes.

Method 1:

```
Object object = new Object();     // Different variables
Object object2 = new Object();
.
.
.
```

Method 2:

```
Object object = new Object();
.
.
object = new Object();          // Reuse the same variable
.
```

Is this just different of coding style or any other reasons, such as reserve memory, better performance?

Comment: Vote for coding style...

Comment: in both cases you are creating 2 instances, there wouldn't be performance impact that is worth caring for references

Comment: One reference pointing to two different `objects`.

Comment: So it's just a matter of coding style, and totally no effect on the program?

Comment: The only memory difference is the second one saves you the memory of a pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method1, you are creating two reference and assiging two different objects.Both objects are not eligible to garbage collector.

At the method2, you are creating one reference and assign a new object and then again you create a new object and assign into the reference. Now your first object did not have a reference, therefore it is eligible for the garbage collector.

Good Luck !!!

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is if your method hangs around for a long time and those variables don't fall out of scope. If the method returns quickly, as nearly all methods do, then the references in the variables will get tossed in such a short amount of time that any difference is irrelevant.

In any case, always prioritize readable and understandable code first and don't do anything complicated or potentially unclear unless there's a specific, measured performance problem that needs fixing. Give your variables meaningful names and keep their scope as limited as it can be, and there won't be any problems.

Answer (score 0):

WheWhen you do

```
Object object = new Object();     // Different variables
Object object2 = new Object();
```

You are creating two objects where object  and object2 are references to them . Here intention is you will be using both the objects simultaneously.

When you do

```
Object object = new Object();
.
.
object = new Object();          // Reuse the same variable
```

Here still you are creating two objects but once you are doing object = new Object() second time , first object is eligible for GC provided its no more
used anywhere else.

So, Which way  you  should go for depends on requirement. But in terms of performance i dont see much impact except in second case, first object is eligible for GC
if you have not passed the object reference anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

When you reuse an the existing variable (as in your second example), you would have lost reference to the first object that you created. If no other variable references it, it will be garbage collected by JVM.